# Constructing a 2d interpolator given scattered input data

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

I have three lists as follows:

```
x = [100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0]

y = [300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 7500.0, 7500.0, 7500.0, 75000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0]

z = [100.0, 95.0, 87.5, 77.5, 60.0, 57.0, 52.5, 46.5, 40.0, 38.0, 35.0, 31.0, 30.0, 28.5, 26.25, 23.25, 23.0, 21.85, 20.125, 17.825, 17.0, 16.15, 14.875, 13.175, 13.0, 12.35, 11.375, 10.075, 10.0, 9.5, 8.75, 7.75, 7.0, 6.65, 6.125, 5.425, 5.0, 4.75, 4.375, 3.875]
```

Each entry of each list is read as a point so point 0 is (100,300,100) point 1 is (75,300,95) and so on.

I am trying to do 2d interpolation, so that I can compute a z value for any given input `(x0, y0)` point.

I was reading that using meshgrid I can interpolate with `RegularGridInterpolator` from scipy but I am not sure how to set it up when I do:

```
x_,y_,z_ = np.meshgrid(x,y,z) # both indexing ij or xy
```

I don't get values for `x_,y_,z_` that make sense and I am not sure how to go from there.

I am trying to use the data points I have above to find intermediate values so something similar to scipy's `interp1d` where

```
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
```

where I can later call `f(any (x,y) point within range)` and get the corresponding `z` value.

Comment: `meshgrid` doesn't interpolate. And what you're describing sounds as if `x[i]`, `y[i]` and `z[i]` correspond to one another. In this case you can work with `zip(x,y,z)`. `meshgrid` is for something very different: it would create a grid with the given coordinates along each axis...

Comment: I understand that meshgrid doesn't interpolate but from scipy's RegularGridInterpolator I was reading that I need to build a meshgrid to interpolate in 3d, anyway given your interesting thought how do I interpolate using zip(x,y,z)?

Comment: You can't. Your description doesn't fit to 3d interpolation at all. You need to explain what is it that you're trying to do. Where are you interpolating from where? Try coming up with a [mcve].

Comment: Please check edit, I am trying to get a value of z for any given x and y within range just like what interp1d does for x and y but with another dimension added.

Comment: OK. What you need is 2d interpolation. The input is your _non-gridded_ (scattered) points. You should take a look at [`scipy.interpolate.gridddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) for interpolating at a given set of points, or the [underlying interpolator object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator) for a callable.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of rewriting a large part of your question knowing what you're really trying to do (with the intention of using this question as a reference later). Please read it and make sure you agree with the changes, and feel free to revert them as necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 2d interpolation over scattered data. I'd default to using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` in this case, but you seem to want a *callable* interpolator, whereas `griddata` needs a given set of points onto which it will interpolate.

Not to worry: `griddata` with 2d cubic interpolation uses a [`CloughTocher2DInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator). So we can do exactly that:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp

x = [100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 75.0, 50.0, 0.0]
y = [300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 500.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 700.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 3000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0, 7500.0, 7500.0, 7500.0, 75000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0, 10000.0]
z = [100.0, 95.0, 87.5, 77.5, 60.0, 57.0, 52.5, 46.5, 40.0, 38.0, 35.0, 31.0, 30.0, 28.5, 26.25, 23.25, 23.0, 21.85, 20.125, 17.825, 17.0, 16.15, 14.875, 13.175, 13.0, 12.35, 11.375, 10.075, 10.0, 9.5, 8.75, 7.75, 7.0, 6.65, 6.125, 5.425, 5.0, 4.75, 4.375, 3.875]

interpolator = interp.CloughTocher2DInterpolator(np.array([x,y]).T, z)
```

Now you can call this interpolator with 2 coordinates to give you the corresponding interpolated data point:

```
>>> interpolator(x[10], y[10]) == z[10]
True
>>> interpolator(2, 300)
array(77.81343)
```

Note that you'll have to stay inside the convex hull of the input points, otherwise you'll get `nan` (or whatever is passed as the `fill_value` keyword to the interpolator):

```
>>> interpolator(2, 30)
array(nan)
```

Extrapolation is usually meaningless anyway, and your input points are scattered in a bit erratic way:

[image: location of base points for interpolation]

So even if extrapolation was possible I wouldn't believe it.

---

Just to demonstrate how the resulting interpolator is constrained to the convex hull of the input points, here's a surface plot of your data on a gridded mesh we create just for plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# go linearly in the x grid
xline = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 30)
# go logarithmically in the y grid (considering y distribution)
yline = np.logspace(np.log10(min(y)), np.log10(max(y)), 30)
# construct 2d grid from these
xgrid,ygrid = np.meshgrid(xline, yline)
# interpolate z data; same shape as xgrid and ygrid
z_interp = interpolator(xgrid, ygrid)

# create 3d Axes and plot surface and base points
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, z_interp, cmap='viridis',
                vmin=min(z), vmax=max(z))
ax.plot(x, y, z, 'ro')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Here's the output from two angles (it's better to rotate around interactively; such stills don't do the 3d representation justice):

[image: first shot of surface plot]
[image: second shot of surface plot]

There are two main features to note:

1. The surface nicely fits the red points, which is expected from interpolation. Fortunately the input points are nice and smooth so everything goes well with interpolation. (The fact that the red points are usually hidden by the surface is only due to how pyplot's renderer mishandles the relative position of complex 3d objects)
2. The surface is cut (due to `nan` values) along the convex hull of the input points, so even though our gridded arrays define a rectangular grid we only get a cut of the surface where interpolation makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed I looked into interp2d but that didn't make sense your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: @mb567 no problem. I added some visualization to show how points lying outside the convex hull of the input points behave.